# How to auto close HTML comment in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Is it possible to instruct IntelliJ WebStorm to autocomplete HTML comment? When I type:

```
<!--
```

editor should close the comment automatically, so the result would look like this:

```
<!-- {CURSOR} -->
```

---

This behavior is enabled by default for HTML tags. If I type `<div>` the editor auto-closes the tag `<div>{CURSOR}</div>`

Comment: Sure, just make a simple Live Template that will do that for you -- see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-live-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for this; you can either use **Code | Comment with Line (Block) Comment** actions or add comments or create a custom Live Template for comments, like

[image]